# Install python packages in anaconda

Tags: python, installation, anaconda

Did anyone who succesfully install taynaud/python-louvain library?
I downloaded a file from the [website](https://web.archive.org/web/20200621145023/https://bitbucket.org/taynaud/python-louvain/downloads/) and installed it by 'pip' command (from Anaconda root directory)

```
$ pip install /Users/sundong/downloads/taynaud-python-louvain-f56ac904d92c/
```

Seems like it is installed successfully.

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): python-louvain==0.4 from file:///Users/sundong/downloads/taynaud-python-louvain-f56ac904d92c in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): networkx in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from python-louvain==0.4)
Building wheels for collected packages: python-louvain
Running setup.py bdist_wheel for python-louvain
Stored in directory: /Users/sundong/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/2a/50/5c/740608e77d3b5fb8d19060237f3e7fd6ff8e391ad80e54dcb3
Successfully built python-louvain
```

However when I import community module, ImportError appears.
`ImportError: No module named community`

What are the normal steps to install this library? I'm using Mac OS X, just in case.

I also tried below command in anaconda directory.

```
$ python /Users/sundong/downloads/taynaud-python-louvain-f56ac904d92c/setup.py install
```

However the result is as follows.

```
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing requirements to python_louvain.egg-info/requires.txt
writing python_louvain.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to python_louvain.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to python_louvain.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing entry points to python_louvain.egg-info/entry_points.txt
warning: manifest_maker: standard file 'setup.py' not found
error: package directory 'community' does not exist
```

Comment: have you tried `pip install python-louvain`?

Comment: If you want the latest non-stable development version you can go with `pip install hg+https://bitbucket.org/taynaud/python-louvain`

Answer (score 2):

Oh problem solved.
It just worked by throw a command
`python setup.py install` from where setup.py file is located.
It's a bit surprise that my python env is already set to Anaconda and the package is automatically installed into the anaconda site-package folder.
Maybe my first approach was too complicated.

Answer (score 0):

conda install -c marufr python-igraph

conda install -c vtraag louvain

Comment: maybe add some context what those commands and  their options are for?